# get_class in static method and inheritance (php)

Tags: php, inheritance, static

We have a code

```
class ParentClass {
  public static function getName() {
    return get_class(self);
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}

echo ParentClass::getName(); # => 'ParentClass'
echo ChildClass::getName(); # => 'ParentClass'
```

if I use get_class($this) there is the same result. Also for self::$this, static::$this etc

Any way to get child class name without adding methods to child class for this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll have to use [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php), which binds late. Only available since PHP 5.3 though.

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 5.5 we can use `static::class` instead of `get_called_class`:

```
class ParentClass {
  public static function getName() {
    return static::class;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}

echo ParentClass::getName(); # => 'ParentClass'
echo ChildClass::getName(); # => 'ChildClass'
```